# PHP find & replace - newbie

Tags: php, replace

So I have some text that I need to replace with some other text PLUS the original text itself.

It's for a Wordpress hook, here's the function I'm using:

```
function ad_content($content) {
    if (is_single() || is_page()) {
        $content = preg_replace('(A)','B',$content,1);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter ('the_content','ad_content');
```

The thing is that this will simply replace A with B, what I need is to replace A with A+B, so I guess I'll first have to find A and make it into a variable or array and then find it again, this time replacing it with the variable+another variable that has text B in it.

Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the matched content in the replace parameter, it's available in the $1, $2, etc. for each group in the pattern

`$content = preg_replace('(A)','$1 B',$content,1);`

See the documentation of [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: That sounds about right - I'll test. Can I put variables in there since my B string is pretty huge... so would this work: $content = preg_replace('(A)','\$1 $variableforB',$content,1);

Comment: @kat I believe the correct syntax whould be `$content = preg_replace('(A)','$1 ' . $variableforB, $content,1);` or `$content = preg_replace('(A)',"\$1 $variableforB", $content,1);` but you have to test

Answer (score 1):

you can use str_replace

```
$str = "old";
$final = str_replace($str,"new".$str,$str);
echo $final;
```

Above code will output **oldnew**

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` function :) Take a read here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Please don't use link only answers, especially to that chud of a site. Good answers should explain the problem and show how to fix it without sending the user to another site. Ones that only have a link really just show your prowess using a google search.

Comment: also when referencing a function its usually better to reference it from its documentation source, for str_replace instance the php.net site http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: OK. But I want to keep the original text, just add to it. So I search for A and replace it with A+B.

Comment: He shouldn't be down voted because of a link answer. You can't just give code to a new PHP user and accept them to learn from it, you need to link to a documentation. And w3schools is an okay website. I like it because it provides references and a ton of examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is called string building so you can search for that for more help, but as a start you can try

```
$content .= " additional content";
echo $content;
```

see the affect that has.